# how to use imageview as spinner

Tags: java, android

i ve an issue that i use an imageview dropdown but I don't know how to set data to imageview, so if there is anyone who can help me.i want to use it like an spinner when u click the spinner it display data that u fetch it in it , so my question is how to fetch data to image view and display it
this is my code :

```
dropDownArrow2 =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.dropDownImage2);
 dropDownArrow2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            alimentsAutoComp.showDropDown();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

From you post I understand you have a spinner and an imageview next to it and you want to expand the spinner when the user clicks on the imageview. You can call the performClick() method of the spinner view inside your imageview's listener:

```
Spinner yourSpinnerView = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.yourSpinnerView);
dropDownArrow2 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.dropDownImage2);
dropDownArrow2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        yourSpinnerView.performClick();
    }
});
```

If you want to populate the spinner with data you can copy the code from the developer's website [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner#Populate). Not sure what you mean about adding data to the imageview.

Comment: thank you a lot , but i have only an image view and i want to use it like an spinner when u click the spinner it display data that u fetch it in it , so my question is how to fetch data to image view and display it ?

Comment: @khaliloosbenk what sort of data do you want to fetch? Strings? They would have to go on a separate view. Are you just trying to programmatically change the image source of the imageview?

Comment: yeaaah just a list of string.

Comment: @khaliloosbenk so you have an image, you click on it and on that image you want to display some text? Does the image stay in the background or is it replaced by the text? I still don't understand how this will resemble a spinner and also if you want to have teh same effect, why not use a spinner in the first place?